# What Queue or queues is a camel route listening on

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, karaf

How can I determine what, if any, ActiveMQ queue a camel route is a consumer of?    The route is running as a bundle within Karaf.

Comment: Can you tell more at what time you need to know that, is it at runtime via some monitoring solution, or is just during developing an application. And must it be a Camel route, can it be other applications that read from JMS queues?. There are also Karaf Camel commands you can use at runtime to output the Camel routes / endpoints it uses and there you can see the jms/activemq queue/topic names.

Comment: During run-time (so I am looking at it from an operational perspective) I would like to be able to run a query, command or something to see what  the camel route I am running is connecting to as a consumer.  I think the  commands you mentioned by be what I am looking for.  Do you have them handy or should I just start looking thru Karaf documentation?   re Camel routes, that happens to be what I am using.

Comment: You should have the camel commands in Karaf already, eg they start with `camel` in the shell. There are commands to list endpoints, dump routes in xml, and whatnot, so you should be able to get the details via those.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define it yourself. Every Camel route starts with a `from` statement. For ActiveMQ this would look somehow like this

```
from("activemq:queue:myAwesomeQueue")...
```

This route would create an ActiveMQ consumer that consumes every message arriving on the `myAwesomeQueue`.

The connection to the broker is "hidden" behind the `activemq:`. This is a Camel component (the [ActiveMQ component](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html)) that needs to be configured to connect to the broker.

EDIT: Add operational perspective

[Hawtio](http://hawt.io/) is a webconsole that uses [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) to get data. Jolokia makes JMX information available through a REST API.

If JMX is enabled, you can get loads of information about the CamelContext and/or ActiveMQ. For example the endpoint of an ActiveMQ consumer as in your case.

Unfortunately I can't upload a screenshot because the image domain of SO is blocked, but Google gives you lots of them.

Comment: I should have specified I am asking from an operational perspective, not a programming perspective.  We deployed a roue that was not consuming messages from the queue we thought it should have.  I am looking for a way to query Karaf container or ActiveMQ to see what routes connect to which queues.

Comment: I updated my answer to add the operational perspective